# A problem when rendering a Native Base component

Tags: react-native, native-base

I have a problem with React Native application. How to use the `<NativeBaseProvider>`, because I can't understand what is this error meaning:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite 
components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you 
might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

This error is located at:
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View
    in StyledNativeComponent (created by Styled(View))
    in Styled(View) (at Box/index.tsx:87)
    in Box
    in Container
    ...
```

Here is my code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import type {Node} from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, ScrollView, StatusBar, StyleSheet, Text, useColorScheme, useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';
import { TabView, SceneMap } from 'react-native-tab-view';
import { NativeBaseProvider, Container, Header, Body, Title, Left, Right, Icon } from 'native-base';

const App: () => Node = () => {
  const layout = useWindowDimensions();
  const FirstPage = () => (
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#F0FFFF'}}></View>
  )
  const SecondPage = () => (
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'}}></View>
  )
  const renderScene = SceneMap({
    first: FirstPage,
    second: SecondPage,
  });

  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
  const [routes] = React.useState([
    {key: 'first', title: 'Game'},
    {key: 'second', title: 'Highscores'},
  ]);
  const indexChange = (index) => {
    setIndex(index);
    if (index === 1) {

    }
  } 
  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider>
      <Container>
      <Header style={{backgroundColor: '#00BFFF'}}>
        <Left>
          <Icon name='menu' style={{ color: '#fff' }} />
        </Left>
        <Body>
          <Title>SPEEDGAME</Title>
        </Body>
        <Right/>
      </Header>
    </Container>
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  );
};
```

Can you guys help me with this problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe native-base has a `Title` component, or at least I didnt see one in the docs. Try the `Text` component

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have found out that my code is written in an old Native-Base version. After updating the code to the latest version, everything works well now.